# Using AsyncTask with Runnable vs Creating AsyncTask Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-threading

I recently came across a code snippet that used Runnable with AsyncTask, which I was not familiar with previously.

```
  AsyncTask.execute{

   /* Some code to run in Background
    * ...
    * ...
    */

   runOnUiThread{
     //run on main thread, just like onPostExecute
   }

 }
```

I would like to know how does this compare with following way where we create an AsyncTask class?

```
    class MyAsyncTask : AsyncTask<Unit, Unit, String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Unit): String {...}
        override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {...}
    }
```

Are there any performance or other downsides of the first method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has any thing to do with performance. They are just different ways that you could use to implement this action. If I was writing this code, I would create a class and implement it there.